# Remove columns with uniform values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe with 100+ columns. I want to filter those columns based on their nonuniformity.
Ex. if there're columns with more than 90% (or 95% or 99%) NAs (or 0-s, or -999, or whatever value), remove them from dataframe.

I can remove with NAs, or 0-s, but the problem is I don't know what value it will be.
Ex. of removing NAs with more than 90% `df[, which(colMeans(!is.na(df)) > 0.9)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `table` to count the number of occurence of each value, when the maximum of these values exceeds the needed threshold you can discard the column.

In the following toy example, `x`, `y` and `z` are "constant". For `x` there are 96% of `NA` values, for `y` there are 99% of `0` and for `z` there are 97% of `-1` (but any value would work).

```r
set.seed(26012023)
df <- data.frame(w = rnorm(100), x = c(rep(NA, 96), rnorm(4)), y = c(rep(0, 99), rnorm(1)),
                 z = c(rep(-1, 97), rnorm(3)))

apply(df, 2, function(x, cutoff = .95) {
   tab <- table(x, useNA = "ifany")
   max_val <- max(tab)
   max_val >= cutoff * length(x)
})

#     w     x     y     z 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: thx @thothal. That seems to be the correct solution. But I'm sure that some library with the same functionality exists

Comment: I would argue that for something as simple as that loading a library is an overkill and no need to make yourself dependent on yet another library.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a toy example, defining the following `data.frame` named `df`

```
# Seed to make it reproducible
  set.seed(12345)

  df <- data.frame(cbind(Var1 = c(rep(10,19),1),
                         Var2 = sample(letters[1:5],20, prob = c(0.8,0.1,0.5,0.25,0.25), replace = T),
                         Var3 = sample(c("Yes","No"), 20,  prob = c(.95, .05), replace = T),
                         Var4 = sample(1:3, 20, replace = T),
                         Var5 = c(rep(NA,15),rep(1,5))))
```

Then we compute the maximum frequency of a single value for each colum and finally we delet those that exceed the required value

```
# Calculate the maximum frequency for a single value for each column
  aux <- apply(df,2,function(x) max(prop.table(table(x, useNA = "ifany"))))     
# Define new.df as df whithout the columns that have a value more than a 90% of times
  new.df <- df[,-which(aux>.9)]
```

Comment: Your code would not catch `NAs`  so you should use `useNA` in `table`. This is then however pretty much the same as my answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you, you're right. I did not take into account the `NA`